# how to set data viewer list to variables

Tags: list, variables, thunkable

In thunkable , I need to set a data viewer list to a variable , a list is stored in the variable
using the following code :
Set exerciseList to ( exerciseList + input exercise box's text  )

[I tried using ths block but it didnt work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rGuSH.png)